# Assign value into linq expression Select statement

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to assign value into `Select` statement and want to convert `Date` in specific string format.

I'm trying to convert my existing `Date` into `DateISO 8601 standard format.`

```
IEnumerable<message> messageObj= // list of message from DB;
messageObj.Select(x => x.created_at= DateTime.Parse(x.created_at.ToString("s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))).ToList();
```

I'm unable to use `ToString` for `created_at` inside `linq lambda expression`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have just assigned `messageObj` to null one line before. Is this the actual code ?

Comment: A `DateTime` has no format, what are you doing there? Converting an existing `DateTime` to a `string`, then trying to parse it back to `DateTime`. So a no-op at best.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: The provided code suggests `message.created_at` is of `DateTime` type. 
The "ISO 8601 format" is applicable to a string representation of a Date but not to a `DateTime` value itself. Moreover, the `s` standard format [strips timezone offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Sortable) so you may end up with a mangled DateTime value using such transformation.

Comment: Also, `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is pointless here. [Quote](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Sortable): _The "s" standard format specifier represents a custom date and time format string that is defined by the DateTimeFormatInfo.SortableDateTimePattern property. The pattern reflects a defined standard (ISO 8601), and the property is read-only. Therefore, it is always the same, regardless of the culture used or the format provider supplied. The custom format string is "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"._

Comment: @DmitryEgorov Thanks for bringing up this point, could you please suggest How to achieve DateTime value in IS0 8601.?

Comment: @RajGauravSrivastava: a `DateTime` value is [internally stored as 64-bit integer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,130), therefore a string format (which IS0 8601 effectively is) cannot be applied to it. The answers provided by @HimBromBeere and @TimSchmelter suggest options to get the desired string values.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry

Answer (score 1):

Linq is designed for querying, (that´s what the Q stands for), not updating. Modifying an item in your collection is therefor a bad idea, use a classic for-loop

```
List<message> messageObj= // list of message from DB;
for(int i = 0; i < messageObj.Count; i++)
{
    messageObj[i].created_at = ...;
}
```

However a `DateTime` is just a number (of miliseconds from a given start) and therefor has no format. What you want instead is a formatted string-representation of your date. To do this you´ll need a second variable or member, e.g. `formatDate` of type `string`.

```
    messageObj[i].formatDate = messageObj[i].created_at.ToString("s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clarify your question -- do you want either:

1. to retrieve a list of dates from your database per [@TimSchmelter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44519117/1037948)
2. to retrieve the messages themselves (so you could use them elsewhere too), and then format all or part of them per [@HimBromBeere's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44519042/1037948)

For the first, basically what Tim already said (I don't think 's' format needs a culture as it's a standard):

```
// materialize with ToList
var datesOnly = YourGetMessagesFrom(DB).Select(m => m.created_at.ToString("s")).ToList();
```

Also note that in your original question you mention starting with an `IEnumerable<message>`; it (and the possibly more appropriate `IQueryable<message>`) may lead to lazy-loading, meaning your ORM could actually make a database call to fetch the formatted dates rather than use already retrieved message objects.